# When deploying a docker image to a GCP Kubernetes cluster, what architecture should it have?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I built an image from an Apple M1 Max Macbook, using the `--platform=linux/amd64` argument. However when I deploy it to a GCP K8 cluster, I get a pod status of `Does not have minimum availability` with the following in the logs `error: standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`. Am I using the wrong `platform` argument?

Edit:

Dockerfile

```
#Deriving the latest base image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8-slim-buster

#Labels as key value pair
LABEL Maintainer="thorcheese"



COPY requirements.txt /usr/app/src/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /usr/app/src

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/app/src

CMD [ "python", "./execute.py"]
```

Docker commands:

```
docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t example/image:0.0.1 .

docker push example/image:0.0.1
```

example.py

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: p2e-daily-updates-kub
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: p2e-daily-updates-kub
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: p2e-daily-updates-kub
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: p2e-daily-updates-kub
          image: example/image:0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: p2e-bots-secrets
                  key: TOKEN
            - name: slack_channel
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: p2e-bots-secrets
                  key: slack_channel
            - name: slack_token
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: p2e-bots-secrets
                  key: slack_token
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

kubectl command:
`kubectl apply -f example.yml`

Errors:

```
Does not have minimum availability

Pod errors: CrashLoopBackOff

standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

Comment: The error `exec format error` means that the file format of a binary executable has a problem. In your case, that probably means compiled for the wrong CPU architecture. Edit your question and include the Dockerfile and build commands for the container and any programs within the container. 2) Check that the Dockerfile `FROM` is pulling the correct container architecture (tag).

Comment: @JohnHanley updated with the above files. Also, if it helps, it is running without these errors on my docker-desktop K8 cluster.

Comment: Running on which CPU architecture?

Comment: The docker desktop k8 cluster is running on my Apple M1 Max Macbook, so an Arm-based architecture, I presume.

Comment: That means the container is built for the M1 and not for Intel. Instead of trying to figure out cross-architecture builds, launch a VM or use Cloud Build.

Comment: OK i can try that, but when I use `docker image inspect` to inspect the image, it says `"Architecture": "amd64"`. Also docker desktop shows the container's image as amd64

Comment: It may say one thing but the error message means another. Try building the same container using an Intel system.